# Xamarin Android with an external library failing resolution of R$attr

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dex

I'm working on a production Xamarin Forms Android application and I'm experiencing a strange runtime crash.

The application crashes at runtime with the following stack trace due to not finding the class R$attr on the dexpath (which I verified is present in the final APK after seeing this class):

```
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/jumio/nv/mrz/R$attr;
[AndroidRuntime]    at jumio.nv.mrz.d.prepareDraw(MrzOverlay.java:10)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.jumio.sdk.presentation.BaseScanPresenterBase.measure(BaseScanPresenterBase.java:267)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.jumio.gui.DrawView.onMeasure(DrawView.java:67)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:27145)
.
.
.
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.jumio.nv.mrz.R$attr" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~ZyoczjERvgYKNWuGzNseqg==/test.app-0W68p96d8t_tiQAIAwXmUw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~ZyoczjERvgYKNWuGzNseqg==/test.app-0W68p96d8t_tiQAIAwXmUw==05-04 03:15:11.461 E/AndroidRuntime(18242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8425)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
[AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
```

Using MVVMCross, Xamarin Forms 4.6, and a binding I've made of this 3rd party library. I can use other functionality and even screens from their library fine, but for this particular screen I get this unfortunate runtime crash when navigating to this screen.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: can you give some info about the screen which is crashing

Comment: Sure. It's an android screen with a header and an overlay control that displays the camera and scans a document. It is crashing though while trying to load a resource from the R$attr file, even though I have confirmed that value is present in the AAR, and is in its own android binding library. The final R.txt also includes these values as well as the value on the dexpath in the final APK built by Xamarin. Whenever I try to load this screen, I get the crash above.

Comment: Try to delete the bin and obj files and restart .

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I have tried that, unfortunately that has not fixed my issue. I have also created a completely separate test project with the same problem when using these bindings. I'm not sure what even causes this R$attr issue.